# What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing?

Tags: java, autoboxing

When the Java compiler autoboxes a primitive to the wrapper class, what code does it generate behind the scenes?  I imagine it calls:

- The valueOf() method on the wrapper
- The wrapper's constructor
- Some other magic?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `javap` tool to see for yourself.  Compile the following code:

```
public class AutoboxingTest
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Integer a = 3;
        int b = a;
    }
}
```

To compile and disassemble:

```
javac AutoboxingTest.java
javap -c AutoboxingTest
```

The output is:

```
Compiled from "AutoboxingTest.java"
public class AutoboxingTest extends java.lang.Object{
public AutoboxingTest();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_3
   1:   invokestatic    #2; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   4:   astore_1
   5:   aload_1
   6:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   9:   istore_2
   10:  return

}
```

Thus, as you can see, autoboxing invokes the static method `Integer.valueOf()`, and autounboxing invokes `intValue()` on the given `Integer` object.  There's nothing else, really - it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: It's interesting to note that it calls valueOf(int) instead of new Integer(int) to convert int to Integer. valueOf does object caching for the first 1000 or so integers.

Comment: @Craig: to be precise, -128 to 127 **must** be cached, other values may be cached by an implementation.

Comment: Also worth noting that the compiler doesn't *have* to use Integer.valueOf - the language specification only requires that a.intValue() == 3.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann To be even more precise, you can't redefine the lower bound of the cache (except with some dirty hacks) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633158/why-does-the-jvm-allow-to-set-the-high-value-for-the-integercache-but-not-the

Answer (score 10):

I came up with a unit test that proves that Integer.valueOf() is called instead of the wrapper's constructor.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotSame;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Boxing {
    @Test
    public void boxing() {
        assertSame(5, 5);
        assertNotSame(1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look up the API doc for [Integer#valueOf(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)), you'll see it was added in JDK 1.5.  All the wrapper types (that didn't already have them) had similar methods added to support autoboxing.  For certain types there is an additional requirement, as described in the JLS:

> If the value *p* being boxed is `true`, `false`, a `byte`, a `char` in the range `\u0000` to `\u007f`, or an `int` or `short` number between `-128` and `127`, then let *r1* and *r2* be the results of any two boxing conversions of *p*. It is always the case that *r1* == *r2*. [§5.1.7](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#190697)

It's interesting to note that `long`s aren't subject to the same requirement, although Long values in the `-128..127` range are cached in Sun's implementation, just like the other integral types.

I also just discovered that in my copy of [The Java Programming Language](http://www.informit.com/title/0321349806?aid=9f15cdfa-4e22-40dc-bfc9-cdc6322be0fd), it says `char` values from `\u0000` to `\u00ff` are cached, but of course the upper limit per the spec is `\u007f` (and the Sun JDK conforms to the spec in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting something like [jad](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html) and decompiling code a lot.  You can learn quite a bit about what java's actually doing.