# Which method on the wrapper class is getting called when boxing a primitive in Java

Tags: java

Which method in the `Integer` class will be used when you do `Integer i = 1;`

I'm pretty sure that it's not the constructor, it might be the `valueOf()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/408661/851811)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valueOf:

Here's the output of javap:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=2, Args_size=1
   0:   iconst_1
   1:   invokestatic    #16; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   4:   astore_1
   5:   return
  LineNumberTable:
   line 5: 0
   line 6: 5
```

Answer (score 5):

It is `Integer.valueOf(int)` similarly for Boolean, Byte, Character, Long, Float and Double.

Note: for Boolean and Byte all possible values are cached.
For Character, the values 0 to 127 are cached.
For Short and Long values -128 to 127 are cached.
For Integer -128 to 127 are cached by default, however the maximum can increase using a number of options.

This can lead to surprising behaviour with

```
System.out.println((Integer) (int) -128 == (Integer) (int) -128);
System.out.println((Integer) (int) -129 == (Integer) (int) -129);
```

prints

```
true
false
```

Not sure what you need to cast `-128` with `(int) -128` for this to compile in Java 7.

Comment: I was looking into the Integer source for the cache stuff, that's why I was wondering with method was used while boxing because the constructor doesn't use the '+-127 cache'.

Comment: The constructor has to create a new object every time, it has no choice.  One of my pet hates is people using `new Boolean(flag)` ;)

Answer (score 3):

It actually is `valueOf()`. Take a look at this possible duplicate question: [What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/408661/851811).

And particulary for integers in the range -128, 127, you'll never see the constructor invoked when using `valueOf` because `Integer` has these instances cached.