# confusion about doublevalue() in hash tables

Tags: java, casting, hashtable, type-conversion, unboxing

```java
// Demonstrate a Hashtable
import java.util.*;
class HTDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hashtable balance = new Hashtable();
        Enumeration names;
        String str;
        double bal;
        balance.put("John Doe", new Double(3434.34));
        balance.put("Tom Smith", new Double(123.22));
        balance.put("Jane Baker", new Double(1378.00));
        balance.put("Todd Hall", new Double(99.22));
        balance.put("Ralph Smith", new Double(-19.08));

        // Show all balances in hash table.
        names = balance.keys();
        while(names.hasMoreElements()) {
            str = (String) names.nextElement();
            System.out.println(str + ": " +
            balance.get(str));
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Deposit 1,000 into John Doe's account
        ***bal = ((Double)balance.get("John Doe")).doubleValue();***
        balance.put("John Doe", new Double(bal+1000));
        System.out.println("John Doe's new balance: " +
        balance.get("John Doe"));
    }
}
```

1. In line `bal = ((Double)balance.get("John Doe")).doubleValue();` What is the use of `doubleValue`? (i know it converts object to double value ) but program runs okay if i run without this.
2. (correct me if i am wrong)  `balance.get` get here a double object of value `3434.34` and (double ) in front of it does unboxing and converts it into double object in double value then how and why does `doubleValue()` treats this double `3434.34` as object?????

Comment: Please spend a little more time formatting your questions, you'll get better help that way.

Comment: Have you considered using HashMap<String, Double>()? It's faster (not synchronized) and generics would let you avoid typecasting.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got your questions correctly. I will try to explain from the perspective of what I understood your questions to be.

1. Yes, you are right, you do not need **doubleValue()**. It is just a way of explicitly telling Java to unbox. If you do not use `doubleValue()`, Java will unbox it automatically. So, in case if Java had no support for automatically [un]boxing primitive types to the corresponding Object types, then you will need `doubleValue()` as `(Double)balance.get("John Doe")` will return an Object while `bal` is a variable of primitive type.
2. For the second part of your question, in Java `double` is a primitive data type and `Double` is an object type. The Java collections API and hence `Hashtable` only store objects. They do not store primitive types. Hence, `balance.get()` returns an object. You cast it into another object of type `Double`. The `doubleValue()` method is optional here due to the automatic boxing/unboxing provided by Java.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Collections work Only with OBJECT types and not the primitive ones, One of the reasons why the wrapper classes were created, you cannot store `3.4` but u can store `new Double(3.4)`, Yes as you said, you can use the value without its doubleValue but its a standard way of doing things. And for the Implicit calls and conversions, there is a risk of different version of jvms/jre behaving slightly different in such cases, in order to avoid them you would like to do it the standard way , so that it doesnt get impacted

Comment: There's no risk of different JVMs behaving differently. The boxing and unboxing is done by the javac compiler, not the JIT compiler.  See [What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408661/what-code-does-the-compiler-generate-for-autoboxing) .  The method `doubleValue()` exists because auto boxing and unboxing is simply syntactic sugar - it's not the 'standard' way of doing the conversion, it's the *actual* way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In line bal = ((Double)balance.get("John Doe")).doubleValue(); what is the use of doubleValue (know it converts object to double value )
>      but program runs okay if i run without this.

Correct.

> 1. (correct me if I am wrong) `balance.get()` gets a double object of value 3434.34 and (double) in front of it does unboxing

No. There is no `(double)`. There is `(Double)`. That typecasts it from `Object` to `Double`.

> and converts it into double object

Yes.

> in double value

No. It is an object not a value. This phrase is meaningless.

> then how and why does doubleValue() treats this double 3434.34 as object?

It doesn't. It calls Double.doubleValue() which returns a `double`.

This code doesn't use autoboxing at all. The `doublevalue()` calls in this code have been obsolete since Java 1.5 came out about 5 years ago. It also doesn't use Generics. I suspect you are looking at some very old code.