# Iteration in java

Tags: java, iterator

I have to make a custom iterator that iterators through an array endlessly.  I have no clue how to do this considering I've never worked with iterators in java before.  If anyone could help me out at all and explain to me, I'd appreciate it very much.

```
public class Numbers{   
private int[] array;

public Numbers(int[] array){ 
    this.array = array
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Numbers n = new Numbers();
        Iterator num = n.sequence();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (num.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(num.next() + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show us the code for your Numbers class.  Also, if this is homework you should tag it as such.

Comment: @kurtzbot I suspect we're already looking at the entire Numbers class...

Comment: Iterators are by definition "finite" in size.  I suppose you could wrap the for loop inside of a 'for ( ; ; )' loop ?

Comment: Also, I can not change any of the code currently in main.  I can however, add to it.

Comment: @djangofan, actually you can override the next() method and have it return an "infinite" set of data based on the current index. Just look at A. R. S.'s answer for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below:

```
public class Numbers implements Iterable<Integer> {
    private int[] array;
    private int i;
    public Numbers(int[] array) { 
        this.array = array;
        i = 0; 
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() { return true; }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                int j = i;
                i = (i + 1) % array.length;
                return array[j];
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {}
        };
    }
}
```

You could then do:

```
Numbers n = new Numbers(new int[]{1,2,3});
for (int i : n)
    System.out.println(i);  // or anything else
```

This would result in the infinite loop:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   1
>   2
>   ...

Relevant javadocs:
 - [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)
 - [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

---

Another way to do it is just to have an infinite while-loop as such:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);  // or anything else
    i = (i + 1) % array.length;
}
```

Comment: See also [*What code does the compiler generate for autoboxing?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/408661/230513)

Comment: Wouldn't the code for next in this solution be public int getNext()?  Or am I just missing something?

Comment: `int` wouldn't work in this case, you need the `Integer` wrapper class to properly override the `next` method of the `Iterator` interface.

Comment: The [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interface specifies `next()`.

Comment: Alright, I understand now.  Thanks for the help.  Still kinda shaky on the modulus thing but I'll figure it out I suppose.

Comment: The modulus thing is to wrap the index back around back to 0 when it goes out of range. For example, with {1, 2, 3} (length = 3), we start at `i` = 0, next we have `i` = (0 + 1) % 3 = 1, next `i` = (1 + 1) % 3 = 2, and then `i` = (2 + 1) % 3 = 0, - see how we came back to 0? Now the cycle can start again.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically how an iterator works. This example uses a `List`, but you can use an iterator against any collection that implements [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

```
List<String> someList; // assume this has been instantiated and has values in it

ListIterator<String> it = someList.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String value = it.next();

    // do something with value
}
```

Pretty much, you instantiate the iterator by telling the collection to give you a reference to its iterator. Then you loop by calling `hasNext()`, which will keep you going until you have no more elements. The call to `next()` pulls the next item from the iterator and increments its position by one. A call to `remove()` will remove from the list the *last item* returned by `next()` (or `previous()`.)

Note, of course, that I've been using [`java.util.ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead of [`java.util.Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) because the `ListIterator` is a special implementation of `Iterator` optimized for use against lists, like in the example I gave above.

You cannot use an iterator against an array. You'd need to use a vanilla for-loop or convert it into a `List` or another object that implements `Iterable`.

To loop through the above list endlessly, your loop would look something like this:

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String value = it.next();

    // do processing

    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        it = someList.listIterator(); // reset the iterator
    }
}
```

To loop through the array using a for-loop endlessly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i];
    // do something

    if (i == myArray.length - 1) {
        i = 0; // reset the index
    }
}
```

Alteratively you could have your `Numbers` class implement `Iterable` directly.

Comment: Umm modify loop counter inside the  for loop? Dangerous

Comment: @vicfran - The OP wants an infinite loop, so an infinite loop s/he shall receive.

Answer (score 0):

Work with iterators is basically always the same.

First get the iterator from your array:

```
Iterator iterator = yourArray.iterator();
```

Second iterate while it has items:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
  Object element = iterator.next(); 
}
```

Comment: I understand that.  The problem is that I have to make a "custom" iterator that goes an array endlessly.

Comment: What do you mean by custom iterator? I don't understand clearly what you want