# Difference between Long.parseLong(String s) and new Long(String s)?

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I know that the String can be converted to a long using [Long.parseLong(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) method and [Long(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long%28java.lang.String%29) constructor.

```
String str="12356";
Long myvar= Long.parseLong(str);
Long myvar2 = new Long(str);
```

Both of them gives same output. Value of myvar and myvar2 is same. I would like to know which one gives better performance and when to use `parseLong` and when to use new `Long(String s)`.

Comment: Did you meant `Long.parseLong` ? Otherwise, that wouldn't compile.

Comment: @ZouZou: Thanks for pointing that out it was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Do you really mean to box the result of `Long.parseLong`? it does not return `Long`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new Long` will **always** create a new *object*, whereas `parseLong` doesn't.

I advise you to go through the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.parseLong%28java.lang.String,int%29) of each one.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is

- `parseLong` returns a primitive
- `new Long()` will always create a new objecct

Answer (score 0):

If you open look at Long.java source, you can see that Long(String) actually calls parseLong(String).

The only difference is creating a new Long object. Therefore if you ignore object creation cost, they give same performance.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor (`new Long(String)`) calls immediately `Long.parseLong(String)` method. So, if you use `parseLong()` you will omit an extra call. However, they will give a similar performance actually.

The source of Java:

```
public Long(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    this.value = parseLong(s, 10);
}
```

Comment: ... except that you have also created a new object.

Answer (score 0):

*If* the question really means `Long myvar = Long.parseLong(str)` then these are in fact identical in performance, because this line also contains a new `Long` creation via boxing. `parseLong()` is called in both cases, and a new `Long` is created with its field assigned.

If the intent was to create a `long` instead, which is more likely, then `parseLong()` is better and marginally faster for avoiding a pointless object creation.

Comment: Autoboxing uses valueOf() ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408661/what-code-does-the-compiler-generate-for-autoboxing

Comment: Uses `valueOf(long)`, yes. My point is that either way you have all but identical operations: `new Long` which does `this.value = value`, and a call to `parseLong`.

Comment: ... although if you're getting at the fact that `valueOf(long)` caches -128L to 127L, yeah that would be a difference and slight reason to prefer the boxing.