# Why does the JVM allow to set the "high" value for the IntegerCache, but not the "low"?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

We all know that Java has a cache for `Integer` (and some other types) for number in the range `[-128, 127]` which are considered to be "commonly used".

The cache is designed as follow :

```
private static class IntegerCache {
    static final int low = -128;
    static final int high;
    static final Integer cache[];

    static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
            sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            try {
                int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
                i = Math.max(i, 127);
                // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
                h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low) -1);
            } catch( NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // If the property cannot be parsed into an int, ignore it.
            }
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);

        // range [-128, 127] must be interned (JLS7 5.1.7)
        assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    }

    private IntegerCache() {}
}
```

I know that I can extend the `high` value by giving a parameter to the JVM :

```
java -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=xxxx Aclass.class
```

What I don't understand is why aren't we allowed to override the `low` value ?

Note that I was not trying to find a workaround, but instead understand why it is not allowed for some obscure reasons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found out that there is already an unresolved [RFP](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6968657?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab) on this.

Joe Darcy commented on the issue :

> It is conceivable that it would be helpful to cache a greater range of
>   negative number as well, but as of yet there has been no pressing need
>   to do so.

Note that the RFP offer a poor workaround if ever someone was interested in using this before it is handled :

> No workaround possible for increasing
>   the size of the cache apart from Implementing your own cache and
>   reffering to this first before going to the java.lang.Integer class.
>   **This is obviously not good as it requires calls to other classes
>   rather than just the default use of the Integer.valueOf(int i) call**.