# Operator overloading in Java (Integer wrapper class)?

Tags: java

I came across an example in the OCJP book. It says

```
Integer y=new Integer("20");
y++;   (un-wraps it)
System.out.println(y);
```

Now, this would print 21. Hence, it makes me think, how did the compiler even know that at `y++` it should unwrap it to int and increment it? Integer is just a normal class(may is say Wrapper class??), is it operator overloading that is inbuilt inside?

Is there a way I can do this for my own custom class if possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/408668/2231632 - please see if this explanation helps.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses a feature called [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to unwrap that integer and increment it. You cannot implement this feature in your own user-defined classes. It is only available for those wrapper classes for Java primitive types.

Comment: thanks for answering my question, i was not aware of autoboxing and unboxing, could u please confirm what happens in ==, when i do == on two objects, it checks for its reference, and when i do == on strings, it checks in the literal pool ?

Comment: @codemania23 Please search for answers to your questions instead of asking unrelated follow-up questions in comments.

Comment: thanks for the help anyways :), appreciate it !!