# create a new Integer object that holds the value 1?

Tags: java, object, integer

To create a new Integer object that holds the value in java 1 which one of the following is right and what exactly is the difference in the following methods as all print the value?

Method 1 :

```
 Integer p = new Integer(1);
```

Method 2 :

```
Integer p = 1;
```

Method 3 :

```
Integer p = new Integer("1");
```

Using method three I got the following warning :

```
Note: HelloWorld.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
```

Comment: Method 4: `Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1);`

Comment: Some background: If you use `Integer.valueOf(int value);`, then class `Integer` can return previously created `Integer`-objects that have the same value (this works since `Integer`s are immutable).

Comment: @JacobG. Why would I use valueOf method while creating the object the first time and could you please also explain why that is a better method than any of the mentioned ways. Thanks

Comment: @noogler Check [Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904957/7294647)

Comment: @Jacob While your method is certainly correct, I do not see a reason to prefer method 4 over method 2. It generates same result due to autoboxing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You skipped the intended solution:

```
Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

This pattern is known as [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). One may ask what the benefit of this method is. Luckily, the [implementation of class `Integer` is open-source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java), so let's take a look:

```
    public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
        if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
            return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
        return new Integer(i);
    }
```

There seems to be some kind of `Integer`-value cache. If one requests an `Integer` with a value within the cache-range, Java does not create a new object, but returns a previously created one. This works because `Integer`s are immutable. One can even control the upper cache limit with the system property `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=...`.

And why do the other two methods of creating an `Integer` generate a warning? Because they were set deprecated with Java 9.

[`Integer#Integer(int value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-):

> **Deprecated**. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. The static factory `valueOf(int)` is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance. [...]

[`Integer#Integer(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-java.lang.String-):

> **Deprecated**. It is rarely appropriate to use this constructor. Use `parseInt(String)` to convert a string to a `int` primitive, or use `valueOf(String)` to convert a string to an `Integer` object. [...]

And just for completeness, here is the part for [`Integer.valueOf(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-):

> Returns an `Integer` instance representing the specified `int` value. If a new `Integer` instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Integer(int)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache values in the range `-128` to `127`, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

---

EDIT 1: Thanks to [@VGR mentioning that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904830/create-a-new-integer-object-that-holds-the-value-1/49905071#comment86826616_49905071)

```
Integer p = 1;
```

is equivilant to

```
Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

This, however, is only true for `int`-values between `-128` and `127`.  The behaviour is defined in [JLS §5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> [...] If the value `p` being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.28) of type `boolean`, `char`, `short`, `int`, or `long`, and the result is `true`, `false`, a character in the range `'\u0000'` to `'\u007f'` inclusive, or an integer in the range `-128` to `127` inclusive, then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.

---

EDIT 2: Thanks to [@DorianGray, who brought the following to my attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49904830/create-a-new-integer-object-that-holds-the-value-1/49905071#comment86828004_49905071).

While not in the JLS, the version of `javac` I am using (`9.0.4`) does compile the boxing down to `Integer.valueOf(...);` as it is shown in [this answer by Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408668/4216641).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `Integer p = 1;` is functionally identical to this.

Comment: @VGR added. Thanks for the wink =)

Comment: Actually `Integer p = 1` is always equivalent to `Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1)`, it is just a shorter notation.

Comment: I still see the reference to the range of int.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer Yes, not every `int`-value is cached. Only the ones between `-128` and `127` are guaranteed to be chached (as the documentation says, and as is defined in the JLS). Or do I misunderstand your statement?

Comment: I was talking about the fact that `Integer p = 1` is always evaluated as `Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1)` - thats how autoboxing is implemented. They are both using the same cache and are identical in behavior.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer do you have some spec on that? If so, I would gladly add this to my answer.

Comment: Well, interesting, that behaviour is not specified in the JLS link you posted, so I have to correct myself that my statement is not generally true and implementation specific to the VM. I found a diacussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408661/what-code-does-the-compiler-generate-for-autoboxing about that.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer Added. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: Note that even for the values in the -128 and 127 range, the specification does not mandate that `valueOf` will be used. It only says that whatever is used under the hood will return canonical instances. But when you are about to implement a compiler interoperating with the other compilers, you have no choice but to implement it exactly that way, as everything else would break the specification’s guaranty. And now that the constructors are “Deprecated, for removal”, generating code using them would imply generating code that may break in the future. So `valueOf` is the only remaining option.

Answer (score 3):

Method 4, `Integer p = Integer.valueOf(1);` is the recommended way. The JavaDoc says:

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a
>   new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache
>   values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values
>   outside of this range.

Comment: If taking the question as it is written, `Integer.valueOf(1)` is *not* the right solution, as it is *not* guaranteed to create, I quote, "new Integer object".

Comment: @lexicore while being true, what reason could there be to create a new `Integer`-object if another one with same value already exists? `Integer`s are immutable.

Comment: @Turing85 Practically - probably none. For a quiz question it might be significant.

Comment: @lexicore well... weird quiz I would say ;) especially since both C'tors are set deprecated (which is the closest Oracle will ever get to "deleting" some public method or switching it to `private`) =).

Comment: @Turing85 Not that I were surprized by weird quizes. But the question really looks like a quiz question to me.

Comment: @lexicore there is no “right solution” for creating a “new Integer object”, as the deprecation and planned removal of the public constructors is precisely to stop offering a way for creating a “new Integer object”.